# NGINX proxy to server with cache as backup

Tags: nginx

We want to set up an NGINX server that will proxy all requests it receives to an upstream server, but when the upstream server fails/becomes unavailable it should fall back to a local cache of the most recently received files. What's the best way to set this up?

The best way I thought of doing it would be setting the 5xx error documents to something like

```
error_document 500 502 503 504 =200 /cache/;


location /cache/ {
    #Send cached files
}
```

But I'm not sure how to effectively* get NGINX to cache *all* files while still proxying to the upstream and then how to pull the files back from the cache via a location.

<sub>*Without A) filling up the disk very quickly with multiple versions of the same cached file and B) not slowing down requests too much</sub>

Comment: A good starting point may be the nginx [`proxy_cache`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_cache) directive, used with [`proxy_cache_use_stale`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_cache_use_stale) (which will let you use the cache when the upstream server(s) are down). (As for the *all* part: `proxy_ignore_headers` (to ignore headers that would otherwise prevent caching).

Comment: A much more robust solution would be to put a purpose-built caching proxy like Varnish ahead of nginx and the let the caching happen transparently.

Answer (score 0):

If the files do not change on remote server, `proxy_store` may work for you.  e.g.

```
    upstream big {
            server  serverfault.com:80;
    }

    root /somewhere;
    location / {
            try_files $uri @big;
    }
    location @big {
            proxy_pass http://big;
            proxy_set_header Host serverfault.com:80;
            proxy_store on;
    }
```